# Telerik Kendo UI Menu with Controller and Action

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-menu

I am trying to implement a Kendo UI Menu bind from JSON data.

For Now I am getting only links with Controller Value based on  my JSON Data.

For example i am getting this in the href

**href="/MemberManagement"**

MemberManagement is the name of Controller

Is there any way i can add Controller with Action also

Here is the view code i am using

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#menu1").kendoMenu({ dataTextField: "TitleText", dataSource: { transport: { read: { url: "@Url.Action("GetMenuData", "Home")", dataType: "json" } }, schema: { model: { id: "id", hasChildren: "hasChildren", action: "Link" } } } })

    $("#menu1").kendoMenu({
        dataTextField: "TitleText",


        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "@Url.Action("GetList", "Test")",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "id",
                    hasChildren: "hasChildren",
                    ActionName: "ActionName",
                    ControllerName:"ControllerName"

                }
            }

        }
    })
});
$("#menu1").kendoMenu({
    select: onSelect
});

function onSelect(e) {



    alert("Selected: " + $(e.item).children(".k-link").text());
    alert("Selected: " + $(e.item.action).children(".k-link").text());
}
```

**My JsonData**

[{"id":"1","ParentID":"0","TitleText":"Web Application","ControllerName":"MemberManagement","ActionName":"Index","hasChildren":true},{"id":"59","ParentID":"0","TitleText":"App Application","ControllerName":"MemberManagement","ActionName":"Index","hasChildren":true},{"id":"62","ParentID":"0","TitleText":"Driving Application","ControllerName":"MemberManagement","ActionName":"Index","hasChildren":true},{"id":"63","ParentID":"0","TitleText":"Test 15Dec","ControllerName":"MemberManagement","ActionName":"Index","hasChildren":true},{"id":"68","ParentID":"0","TitleText":"Driving Licence","ControllerName":"MemberManagement","ActionName":"Index","hasChildren":true},{"id":"69","ParentID":"0","TitleText":"Tariq-Jan-04-2020","ControllerName":"MemberManagement","ActionName":"Index","hasChildren":true},{"id":"71","ParentID":"0","TitleText":"parent Node","ControllerName":"MemberManagement","ActionName":"Index","hasChildren":true},{"id":"75","ParentID":"0","TitleText":"Rheem Doc","ControllerName":"MemberManagement","ActionName":"Index","hasChildren":true},{"id":"80","ParentID":"0","TitleText":"Member Portal","ControllerName":"MemberManagement","ActionName":"Index","hasChildren":true}]